# Web scraping redirect while curl

Tags: php, facebook, curl, server, php-curl

I am trying to scrape certain page on Facebook. Let's suppose it is `www.facebook.com/ads`

While executing this command:

```
curl "https://www.facebook.com/ads..." ^
  -H "authority: www.facebook.com" ^
  -H "pragma: no-cache" ^
  -H "cache-control: no-cache" ^
  -H "sec-ch-ua: ^\^" Not A;Brand^\^";v=^\^"99^\^", ^\^"Chromium^\^";v=^\^"96^\^", ^\^"Google Chrome^\^";v=^\^"96^\^"" ^
  -H "dnt: 1" ^
  -H "sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0" ^
  -H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36" ^
  -H "viewport-width: 890" ^
  -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ^
  -H "x-fb-lsd: 1" ^
  -H "sec-ch-ua-platform: ^\^"Windows^\^"" ^
  -H "accept: */*" ^
  -H "origin: https://www.facebook.com" ^
  -H "sec-fetch-site: same-origin" ^
  -H "sec-fetch-mode: cors" ^
  -H "sec-fetch-dest: empty" ^
  -H "referer: https://www.facebook.com/ads/..." ^
  -H "accept-language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7" ^
  -H "cookie: datr=1; sb=2; usida=3; oo=4; dpr=5; locale=pl_PL; c_user=6; spin=7" ^
  --data-raw "__user=1&__a=1" ^
  --compressed
```

Everything is fine, I am getting the correct response.

But after converting this command to PHP curl, using [this](https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/) tool, so the code will look like this:

```php
// Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.facebook.com/ads...');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "__user=1&__a=1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authority: www.facebook.com';
$headers[] = 'Pragma: no-cache';
$headers[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Ch-Ua: ^^';
$headers[] = 'Dnt: 1';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0';
$headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36';
$headers[] = 'Viewport-Width: 890';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
$headers[] = 'X-Fb-Lsd: 1';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: ^^Windows^^\"\"';
$headers[] = 'Accept: */*';
$headers[] = 'Origin: https://www.facebook.com';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty';
$headers[] = 'Referer: https://www.facebook.com/ads/...';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7';
$headers[] = 'Cookie: datr=1; sb=2; usida=3; oo=4; dpr=5; locale=pl_PL; c_user=6; spin=7';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

I am getting response that I can log in and after that, I can see that page.

To sum up, in the first case `curl` from bash works fine, in the second case `curl` from php does not work, it requires me to log in.

My question is, why does executing `curl` from PHP require me to log in?

I would like to mention that both cases are executed on the public, AWS server.
I would like to add note that if I execute the same `curl` in php, but from local pc, everything works fine.

Comment: i have the feeling that it has something to do with the Uppercases for facebook specific headers. 

can you call your CURL but using the same Uppercases for the head values like in the CURL from PHP? do you get here a login request as well? if so then lowercase all the haeders in php

Comment: Just to make sure you are aware. Facebook does not allow you to scrape them.